# How do i add a list and an argument?

Tags: python-3.x, join, python-3.6

I am new to python and couldn't work out a solution:

I have a empty list and a command generated from processing user input. i want to merge them so it works as normal command.

```
lst = []
cmd = insert(0,5)
```

i want it to work like

```
lst.insert(0,5)
```

so that output is

```
[5]
```

but with every loop the value of cmd will change.
concatenate, .join or print format doesn't apply here
shall i try class or is there any other easier method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This will **write** `5` to the 0th index of the list

```py
lst = []
lst[0] = 5
# lst is [5] now
```

This will **add** `5` to the end of the list.

```py
lst = []
lst.append(5)
# lst is [5] now
```

This will **remove** the last values from the list.

```py
lst = [5]
lst.pop()
# lst is empty now []
```

You can also use `pop()` at a certain index.

```py
lst = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
lst.pop(2)
# lst is changed to [5, 4, 2, 1]
```

If the user defines the index and the value, you could try something like this:

```py
# The index the user provides has to be <= to the length of the list
lst = []
cmd = input("Give a command:\n").split(" ")  # input must be space-separated
if cmd[0] == "append":
    lst.append(cmd[1])
elif cmd[0] == "insert":
    lst[cmd[1]] = cmd[2]
elif cmd[0] == "pop" and len(cmd) == 1:
    lst.pop()
elif cmd[0] == "pop" and len(cmd) == 2:
    lst.pop(cmd[1])
```

There are some problems in it, like error handling, but it should work if you know what the inputs will be beforehand.

Comment: Could you provide an example input?

Comment: thanks Flip, but my program requires that the user input some command for example ```insert 0 5``` or ```append 5``` with space or other placeholders. then the program process the input to generate command. ```insert(0,5)``` or ```append(5)```. It would have been easier if there is no command but only index and value but as you mentioned above, it can be insert or pop or append. the program need to call that function to the list. i hope i am clear now.

Comment: You can check if what the first word is and do that operation, so `insert 0 5` does `lst[0] = 5`, `pop 0` does `lst.pop(0)` and so on for the rest of the functions.

Comment: thanks Flip. I had this option in mind but tried to find some workaround. i now guess this is the only way ahead.

Comment: Well this is probably the easiest way to do it. Maybe you could find out an easier way to do this, but this way it's easy to do error handling. Like when the list is empty and the user does `pop` that will throw an error and stop the program.